# How does an inverted cup make music in the bathroom?

Tags: acoustics, resonance, vibrations

A *partially* filled inverted cup immersed in a bucketful of water makes *musical* notes, when you turn on the tap and let the water fall continuously into the bucket.

Whereas no music is made if you take a *fully* filled inverted cup and do the same with it.

I wonder why?

Comment: I have never observed the phenomenon you describe, and in particular I'm confused what sort of "musical note" you hear. Can you provide any evidence for it and be more precise as to what the setting is? Is the cup at the bottom of the bucket or floating at the top? Does the note depend on the flow rate of the water or where it enters the bucket, or does it depend on how much the cup is filled?

Comment: Yes, sure.Take a cup, fill three forth with water, and immerse it it a bucket. Slowly make the water flow from the tap making that "turrr" noise.Now bring the cup close to the dripping site, you have resonating sounds!

Comment: ABOUT THE SETUP: The cup is at water surface, with its open end completely underwater. Water falls approximately at the centre of the mouth of the bucket. The pitch of the  sound depends on how much the cup is filled. The intensity of the sound depends on the distance between the cup and the dripping site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trapped air in the cup forms a resonant chamber bounded by the bottom of the glass (now the top), sides of the glass and the water-air interface in the middle of the cup. Air can be compressed and would then be capable of "ringing", possibly with more than one mode. Each mode would be a "musical note". Water is essentially incompressible so a fully filled cup would not have the same phenomenon.